# How to remove twitter-feed from website

Tags: twitter

I was asked by the owners to remove the twitter-feed from their website, but untill now I am unable to find the place where to do that. The website I am working on is:

www.werkelijkheid.com

Answer (score 0):

Where it's located is hard to tell, since every setup is different. It seems as an older site, is it in EE1 or EE2? You'll have to edit the templates via the template manager or look in the global variables or snippets. Also, it can be hiding in an addon(module probably) such as Low Variables.
If you need a hand just give me a shout

Answer (score 0):

This might just be a straight up Twitter embed with no EE add-on involvement at all.

Search your EE templates for the string `twitter-timeline`.

And remove the following two lines:

```
<a class="twitter-timeline"  href="https://twitter.com/search?q=%23BMISXSW%20OR%20%23SXSW" data-widget-id="307176336953319424">Tweets about #BMISXSW OR #SXSW</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```